# Capturing (audio) streams in iOS background apps

Tags: iphone, ios

Let's say you have NPR radio running in the background on iOS... can I create another app that would run simultaneously that'd let me record that stream for playback?

Answer (score 0):

The stock iOS app sandbox will prevent any access to data streams (or other private data) from inside other apps.  If your app requests an audio session for recording from the mic, any background audio playing through the speakers will first be shut down before giving your app access to audio IO.

Comment: Thanks hotpaw, I think it'd be really great if someone could create a Tivo for online radio. I listen to NPR and often times I find myself in need of going back a few seconds to (re)capture a URL they announce or a name I'd like to lookup further. Any ideas how to go about that?

Comment: Does NPR use a public API to stream from their internet site?  If so, write your own NPR player app to connect to their web site; then you will have access to your own app's own audio stream.